# Eclipse can't find xsl template in another file in the same directory

Tags: java, eclipse, xslt, buildpath

I have three xsl documents in the same folder:

- *ooo2xslf0-writer.xsl* which contains
- *images.xsl* which calls a template called *apply-border* in
- *borders.xsl*

Now, *ooo2xslf0-writer.xsl* contains:

`<xsl:include href="images.xsl" /> 
 <xsl:include href="borders.xsl" />`

And so I assume that *apply-border* is available for *images.xsl* when it needs it, but **Eclipse** disagrees.  So, I added:

`<xsl:include href="borders.xsl" />`

to *images.xsl*, and all compiled fine, but at run-time I'm getting an error that *apply-borders* is present twice.

This is someone else's project, and it builds in most environments just fine.  I assume this is just an **Eclipse** dependancy set-up issue but I'm not sure how to resolve it.  The referenced folder is included in the build.

Comment: xsl files would not be checked at compile time, so what is the error which you get when NOT including borders.xsl in images.xsl ?

Answer (score 0):

Which plug-in are you using and is it the most recent version?  It could simply be a bug.